# node.js - end the request immediately?

Tags: node.js

So I have the following code -

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

console.log("Connected!");
res.writeHead(200);

req.on('data', function(data) {
    res.write(data);
});

}).listen(5000);
```

But when I write into chrome `localhost:5000` it just load the page, and then it says that the server didn't sent any data..

I figured out that If I write `req.end();` after the data event, it loads the page perfectly.
 However, I don't want to end the request immediately.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to call `res.end()` at some point, but you can wait for the `req` [to `'end'` first](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_end):

```
req.on('end', function () {
    res.end();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that's all I searched for!